# Show List if contains data else AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

1. In **LoginActivity** showing *single button*
2. And *want to launch* **UploadActivity**, if ***UploadActivity's List contain any data else show alert "No Images found in UploadActivity"***

In short, 
i just want to show alert dialog if upload activity has no data in a List else Launch UploadActivity...

```
btnCheckUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    alertdialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    alertdialog.setMessage("No Images found in UploadActivity");
                    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        });
                    alertdialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

**UploadActivity.java:-**

```
    public class UploadActivity extends Activity  {

            final private static int DIALOG_LOGIN = 1;
            EditText editPersonName, editPersonaEmail, editPersonTelephone, parental_email ;
            TextView editImageName ;
            String fileName;

            static ListView lstView;
            private Handler handler = new Handler();;

            static List <String> ImageList;
            String strPath;

            CheckBox chkOption3;

            TextView tv1, tv2;
            CheckBox chkOption1, chkOption2 ;

            int position ;

            static File f1;

            static String folder = null ;

            Intent i;
            Intent intent ;

            TextView textHeading1;

            static File[] files;
            static File  file ;

            static List <String> it ;

            static String textHeading = null;
            // new Class DB
            final myDBClasss myDb = new myDBClasss(this);

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

            textHeading1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventNameDate1);
            textHeading1.setText(CameraLauncherActivity.folder);


            /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
            ImageList = getSD();

            // ListView and imageAdapter
            lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));              
            }


            public static List <String> getSD()
            {
            it = new ArrayList <String>();
            String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Awesome/";
    f1 = new File (string+ CameraLauncherActivity.folder+ "/");
            files = f1.listFiles ();

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
            file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
            }
            return it;
            }


            public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
            {
            private Context context;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c)
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            context = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ImageList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);              

            if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_upload, null);
            }              

            // ColImgName
            TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgName);
            strPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Get File Name
            fileName = strPath.substring( strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length() );
            file = new File(strPath);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            long length = file.length();
            txtName.setText(fileName);

            // Image Resource
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath,options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


            // ColStatus
            final ImageView txtStatus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
            txtStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.bullet_button);

            // progressBar
            final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //btnUpload
            final ImageButton btnUpload = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Upload
            btnUpload.setEnabled(false);

            startUpload(position);
            }
            });


            return convertView;

            }      
    }
```

Comment: How you are getting the count without starting the `UploadActivity` ? Show the code how you are binding data in `ListView` ?

Comment: @GrIsHu, Exactly same question in my mind.

Comment: You need to use adapter.getCount() instread of lstView.getChildCount()

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Please elaborate or provide any snapshot.

Comment: @Abrahim Neil You are supposed to get all the data in your `LoginActivity` and you need to check for the size of the data in whichever list you are storing it.

Comment: Are you using `ImageList` array to add the data into your listview ?

Comment: @GrIsHu if list view doesnot contain any data, then i am just trying to show Alert

Comment: Show your adapter class code please.

Comment: Check out my answer i have shown you the simplest way. @AbrahimNeil

Comment: why you are making your listview as static??

Answer (score 3):

`lstView.getChildCount()` will Returns the number of children in the group.that is you view.so store the refrence of your `ImageAdapter`
and then use `adapter.getcount();`

you can also check for your `ImageList` size as well.

instead of

`if (UploadActivity.lstView.getChildCount() > 0)`

use

`if (imageList.size) > 0)`

or 
`if (adapter.getcount() > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

ListView is a View, calling listView.getChildCount() means :

```
<ListView>
  <TextView></TextView>
</ListView>
```

It doesn't make sense because a ListView have no child. What you need to Do is call your Adapter.getCount();

If you created your Adapter well it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `getSD()` as **public static**  and trying to access it in your `LogincActivity` as below:

```
 btnCheckUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   List<String> dt=new ArrayList<String>();
                    dt=UploadActivity.getSD();
                    if (dt.size()> 0) {
                    Intent intentUpload = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intentUpload);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    alertdialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    alertdialog.setMessage("No Images found in UploadActivity");
                    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        });
                    alertdialog.show();
                }
                }
            });
```

**EDITED:**

Another way is check the condition in your `UploadActivity` only and if no data found then simply show alert and onclick of alert finish the activity as below:

```
   ImageAdapter adapter=new ImageAdapter(this);
  if(adapter.getCount()>0)
 {
     // ListView and imageAdapter
     lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));      
  else
  {

  AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                alertdialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                alertdialog.setMessage("No Images found in UploadActivity");
                alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish(); //Finish your UploadActivity here.
                        }
                    });
                alertdialog.show();
       }
```

Comment: see my adapter code above and i just want to show alert, if UploadActivity.java does not contain any data

Comment: but i want whenever user do tap on CheckUploadActivity (LoginActivity) button then i need to show Alert, if list has no data in UploadActivity.java

Comment: Update your question with the changes you have done. It should work as i have shown. Have you made your `getSD()` method `public static` ?

Comment: i posted my updated code, now getting null pointer exception- using your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44215/discussion-between-abrahim-neil-and-grishu)